# How can fear paralysis be overcome?

Tags: fear

For a person with slight phobia of [fear paralysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear), (A fear that in critical situation when he will most need to react fast to save his (or loved ones) lives he will just be sitting there paralyzed watching his demise...)

[This question answers](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/16434/how-does-fear-paralysis-occur/16435#16435) on the mechanism that causes fear paralysis...

Is there any technique to 'snap out of it'?

I mean we had quite a few wars and cataclysms like tsunamis and earthquakes
 so I would expect for some research done, at least by military...

**How can fear paralysis be overcome?**

Comment: Related: [How is confronting fear approached in many therapies?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/20483/12937)