# How does fear paralysis occur?

Tags: fear

(This question is in relation [to this question here](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/16431/how-can-fear-paralysis-be-overcome))

How does fear paralysis occur? What is the mechanism that makes this happen in brain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Taken from here](https://www.retainedneonatalreflexes.com.au/reflexes/reflexes-fear-paralysis-reflex/)

> The Fear Paralysis Reflex begins to function very early after
> conception and should normally be integrated before birth.  It can be
> seen in the womb as movement of the head, neck and body in response to
> threat.
>
> It is sometimes classified as a withdrawal reflex rather than
> a primitive reflex. If this reflex is retained after birth, it can be
> characterised by withdrawal, reticence at being involved in anything
> new, fear of different circumstances, and is often described as the
> “scaredy cat” child who bears the brunt of teasing by normally
> adventurous children.
>
> **This behaviour appears to be
> due to the reflex’s involvement with the parasympathetic nervous
> system.**  **Most of us are familiar with the “fight or flight” adrenalin
> rush of the sympathetic nervous system, however the FPR taps into the
> opposing system urging the body to “eat and stay”.**  The
> parasympathetic nervous system is intimately involved with the vagus
> nerve.  This nerve comes directly from the brain to aid the organs.
> It bypasses the spinal cord, so in the case of spinal injury we are
> still able to digest our food.  The vagus nerve may be mechanically
> trapped in the skull, chest, abdomen or neck.  Release of this nerve
> entrapment corrects one physical factor that contributes to the
> retention of the FPR.